# How to use dispatch_sync correctly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I am getting twitter time line data from a custom NSObject class and this class has all the coe for calling the API and parse the data. 
I am calling this class from my view controller which has a table view and need to populate the tableview with the data coming from twitter. But due to some issues with the dispatch_sync my view controller calls the twitter class and control comes back to the view controller before the Array (which i am using to populate the tableview) is populated with the data.

Here's some code :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "SpinnerController.h"
#import "proAlertView.h"
#import "SBJson.h"
#import <Accounts/Accounts.h>
#import <Twitter/Twitter.h>

@interface TwitterDataLoad : NSObject<UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    NSMutableData * receivedData;
    NSArray * results;
    NSArray * cellContent;
    NSMutableArray * totalContent;
    SpinnerController * spinner;
    proAlertView * av;
    NSString *json_string;
    NSDictionary * jsonResults;
    SBJsonParser * parser;
    NSMutableArray * dataForTable;

}
@property(nonatomic, strong) ACAccount * account;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray * accounts;
@property(nonatomic, strong) ACAccountStore * accountStore;
@property (nonatomic ,retain) SecondViewController * tbView;

- (void)loadData;

@end

#import "TwitterDataLoad.h"


@interface TwitterDataLoad ()

@end

@implementation TwitterDataLoad
@synthesize tbView;


-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self loadData];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadData
{
    dataForTable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    //Twitter new code

    if (_accounts == nil) {
        if (_accountStore == nil) {
            _accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        }
        ACAccountType *accountTypeTwitter =
        [_accountStore
         accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
        [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeTwitter
                                     withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
                                         if(granted) {
                                             dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                 _accounts = [_accountStore
                                                                  accountsWithAccountType:accountTypeTwitter];

                                                 [self sendRequest];
                                             });
                                         }
                                     }];
    }
}

-(void) sendRequest {

    totalContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _account = [_accounts objectAtIndex:0];

    TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc]
                              initWithURL:
                              [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=test&count=20"]
                              parameters:nil
                              requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    av = [[proAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Getting latest news..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView * indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    indicator.frame = CGRectMake(120, 55, 35, 35);
    [av addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [av setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] withStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [av show];


    [postRequest setAccount:_account];
    [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                             NSError *error) {
        if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&jsonError];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [av dismissAlert];
                [self parseJson];
            });
        }
        else {
            [self showMessage];
        }
    }];

}

-(void)showMessage {

    av = [[proAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Connection Problem" message:@"Please confirm the device is connected to the Internet." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [av setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] withStrokeColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [av show];
}

-(void)parseJson {

    NSMutableArray * complete = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSDictionary * tweets in results)
        {
        NSString * status = [tweets objectForKey:@"text"];
        NSString * date = [tweets objectForKey:@"created_at"];
        NSDictionary * user = [tweets objectForKey:@"user"];
        NSString * artistName = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * screenName = [user objectForKey:@"screen_name"];
        NSString * artistImage = [user objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];
        cellContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:status,date,artistName,screenName,artistImage, nil];
        [complete addObject:cellContent];
        }

        SecondViewController * tmpView = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            tmpView.dataToDisplay = complete;
}
```

This class has been called like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TwitterDataLoad * data = [[TwitterDataLoad alloc] init];
    [data loadData];
    NSArray * temp = dataToDisplay;
}
```

I know I am returning the value in a wrong way but i tried returning it through the loadData message itself to the view controller but it didn't work either so i was just trying this. Please don't care about that.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "control comes back to the view controller before the Array"? What is a control?

Comment: I mean the NSArray * temp = dataToDisplay; this line gets called before the whole code is done running in twitterDataLoad class.

Comment: That is weird. Can you can set breakpoint at `tmpView.dataToDisplay = complete;` and see if it actually has a value? If it does, then you need to set breakpoint at `[data loadData]` and step into it to see how your `NSArray * temp = dataToDisplay` gets called before `[data loadData]`.

Comment: I have already tried it and what happend is after the program has finished running load data function it comes back to the view controller class. And then breakpoint in parse method or sendrequest method gets called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright i figured out the problem with this.
dispatch_sync is doing what it is supposed to do the problem is with the other two statements under which dispatch_sync is been called (the other blocks )

```
[_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountTypeTwitter
                                         withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
```

so this is an asynchronous call and dispatch sync gets called when the program control is back on the main queue as we have it defined like this : dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())
and the method returns before the control is back on the main queue and hence the array doesn't gets any value.
So to solve this i wrote a block in my calling class which gets the return call once this data call is over. email me if you want the whole code @ghostsmitm@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You should call `reloadData` on your `UITableView` once the data has been loaded. You can do this after calling `loadData`.

Comment: I am doing that after that but that's getting called before this whole twitter thing.